# How to define delegates for data types? C#

Tags: c#

C# has [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) for methods. I am looking for quite a similar thing but for data types.

For example, I have a method:

```
public bool IsMatching(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>> query)
```

Is it possible to create my custom "delegate data type"(or whatever it could should be called) and use it everywhere instead of long c# in-buit data types?

```
public delegate Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>> CustomQueryDataType;
...
public bool IsMatching(CustomQueryDataType query)
```

Comment: If you need that in a single file, a simply using alias would do. Otherwise `class CustomQueryDataType : Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>> { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [*Using Alias*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#using-alias)

> Create a using alias directive to make it easier to qualify an
> identifier to a namespace or type

```
using Bob = Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>>;

class Program
{
   public bool IsMatching(Bob query)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

<sub>*Be sure to check out the full documentation, there are several limitations to be aware of*</sub>

You could also use a *class* and inherit from it.

```
public class Bob : Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>>
{
}
```

Side note : Every time you use `dynamic`, you are likely solving a problem by creating 3 more harder to debug and solve runtime problems :)

Comment: Can you tell any reasons why it's a bad idea? Because using alias I would have to create alias in every file. With a class I could apply it globally.

Comment: @DeivydasVoroneckis It is just a little smelly, however if its just a place holder then there is nothing so bad. I have removed that comment, and added another one :)